# For IFR flights that require two alternates, is there a regulation that requires enough fuel to reach the furthest one?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, fuel, easa-regulations

For flights that have two alternate destinations, I'm looking for a reference - either EASA or ICAO - that states that you need enough fuel to reach whichever alternate would require the most fuel to get to.

I think this is common sense, but I need a reference if anyone has it?

Answer (score 1):

EASA OPS 1.255, appendix 1, 1.4 b).

I don't have the text in English here, sorry.

Comment: 1.255 points to “(D) Fuel to reach the destination alternate via the destination, if a destination alternate is required; and”. I read the question as when 2 alternates are required.